# difference between @Param and @RequestParam in Spring

Tags: spring

What is the use of **@Param**.
As i saw a question regarding this.
and i am not able to find the relative answer..
      http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/main.obj?name=priya

We can use @RequestParam to retrieve the value.
My question is that can @Param be used?

Comment: which @Param are you talking about?. Can you put the package name also

Comment: If i have know the package.... i would have read its documentation..

Comment: Is there a reason you weren't able to try it yourself first?

Answer (score 14):

In Spring Framework, `@Param` (`org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param`) is used to bind the method parameter to Query parameter.

Example:

```
@Query("select e from Employee e where e.deptId = :deptId")
List<Employee> findEmployeeByDeptId(@Param("deptId") Long departmentId);
```

Here, Employee is JPA Entity, and @Param is used to bind the method parameter departmentId to Query parameter deptId.

In your case, you are trying to fetch URL Parameter value. `@RequestParam` need to be used. `@RequestParam` is used to bind method parameter to web URL request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Data Rest @Param is used to extract values from request parameters in a RESTful endpoint method.

```
    @RepositoryRestResource
    interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
       @RestResource(path="/findByName")
       Page<Product> findByNameContains(@Param("productName") String 
       name, 
       Pageable pageable);
   }
```

you can now access the endpoint /findByName?productName=name to search for YourEntity resources